# Row span and column span best layout for design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-gridlayout

How to implement design like this i am not sure how to do that sorry for the blurry image.

I have three options

1. Linear Layout with weightsum (Hard)
2. TableLayout  (Not support column span)
3. GridLayout (Don't know)

[image]

I tried this table layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Fir 08 Jul 10:44GMT +01 " />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="ATP Singles Winmbeldon"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="A"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="B"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="C"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="D"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="E"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="F"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="G"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="H"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="I"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="J"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="K"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="L"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think you use Linear Layout divide into 2 horizontal and in first linear layout put textview and in another layout put listView because in 2nd data almost same...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) fits your situation.

In your build.gradle (any versions may be ok):

```
compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:24.1.1"
```

In your layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="Fir 08 Jul 10:44GMT +01"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:columnCount="8">

        <!--
          Header Row
        -->

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_columnSpan="7"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:text="ATP Singles Winmbeldon"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <!-- Spacer for green -->
        <View
                style="@style/CellSpacerStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>


        <!--
          First Row  SF 13:00
         -->

        <!-- Title -->
        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="SF\n13:00"/>

        <!-- Sore 1 -->
        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/row_height"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:text="Raonic M. (6)"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="6"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="4"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="3"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="4"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="5"/>

        <!-- GreenView -->
        <FrameLayout
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/border_size"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/border_size"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/green_circle"/>

        </FrameLayout>


        <!-- Sore 2 -->
        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/row_height"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:text="Federer R. (3)"/>


        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="4"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="6"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="7"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="7"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="5"/>


        <!-- GreenView -->
        <FrameLayout
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/border_size"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/border_size"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/green_circle"/>

        </FrameLayout>


        <!--
        Second Row  SF 15:00
         -->

        <!-- Title -->
        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="SF\n15:00"/>

        <!-- Sore 1 -->
        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/row_height"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:text="Berdych T.(10)"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="6"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="4"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="3"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="4"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="5"/>


        <!-- GreenView -->
        <FrameLayout
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/border_size"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/border_size"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/green_circle"/>

        </FrameLayout>


        <!-- Sore 2 -->
        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/row_height"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                android:text="Murray A (2)"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="4"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="6"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="7"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="7"/>

        <TextView
                style="@style/CellStyle"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="5"/>

        <!-- GreenView -->
        <FrameLayout
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/border_size"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/border_size"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/green_circle"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <!--
         Bottom Brders
        -->
        <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/border_size"
                app:layout_columnSpan="7"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

        <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/border_size"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/border_size"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your style.xml:

```
<resources>
    ...
    <style name="CellStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/border_size</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/border_size</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CellSpacerStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/border_size</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
    ...
</resources>
```

In your dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    ...
    <dimen name="border_size">1px</dimen>
    <dimen name="row_height">54dp</dimen>
    ...
</resources>
```

The result is below:

[image]

Attributes of GridLayout [[document]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html)

- `app:columnCount` is the number of columns of Gridlayout.
- `app:rowCount` is the number of rows of Gridlayout.

Attributes of GridLayout' children [[document]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html)

- `app:layout_columnSpan` is the number of column occupied by this view.
- `app:layout_rowSpan` is the number of span occupied by this view.

Comment: sorry for late reply can you add this green imageview in this table that would be more helpful. see my screeenshot

Comment: And add some explanation about gridlayout so i understand. like app:columnCount="7"
                app:rowCount="2"

Comment: OK I will try to add green imageview, and explain late after.

Comment: @ArpitPatel I updated my answer. Change layout to add green imageView and Add explanation at bottom of my answer.

Comment: ya but green circle is centervertical to row please check my screen shot and thanks for explanation

Comment: if possible then add greencircle in all row (4 green circle out side the table)

Comment: Exactly what i wanted you are a good designer thank you so much.

Comment: i have a question what if i did't specify the rowcount so how it works ??

Comment: If you don't specify rowCount, GridLayout automaticaly determines count of rows. So     there is no need to specify rowCount for your layout.